# Fractal Array Syntax

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an array with 4 values and 6 arrays within each array like this -

[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]

**Inside each of those arrays I placed a copy of this object creating this -**

[0,0,0,0,[[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],[[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],[[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],[[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],[[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],[[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]]]

**I than repeated the process, for each array.**

And than again.

So in total 1[i] + 6[i][i] + 36[i][i][i] + 216[i][i][i] + 1296[i][i][i][i]

My array is doing exactly what I want, and yeah it works fine and no problem with performance or anything! **BUT!!! It looks like this --**

```
var Pl = [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]]],

                     [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]]],

                     [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]]],

                     [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]]],

                     [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]]],

                     [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]],
                              [0,0,0,0,[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]],[0,0,0,0,[],[],[],[],[],[]]]]];
```

Can I do this **allot** smaller?, and maintenance the ability to store 'object values' on each array (all 1500 of them). Would making it smaller with scripts reduce efficiency?

Thank you!

Comment: what is inside of the arrays? or are they just for counting? then take numbers.

Comment: Wow! First time I see ugly but valid question.

Comment: Sorry I am only programming 2 months my first post on internet about code ever.

Comment: Write a recursive function that places a copy of your thing inside itself until a given condition is reached? Its not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: The 4 'values' ** inside each of the arrays represent an X, Y, Angle, Distance, they are objects in a game, and each object has smaller children who can grow and create there own smaller children.

I really hope that makes sense.

Comment: Smaller Syntax would be fantastic, I will look into recursive functions, can you give an example of building arrays like this?

Comment: what about a flat design and a reference to the item of the children?

Comment: I think a JSON tree will be a better representation. We can see what those values mean as JSON object attributes. We can have parent child relationship between those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a recursive function like so.

```js
function createArrayWithDepth(depth) {
  if(depth == 0)
    return [];
  else {
    var subArray = createArrayWithDepth(depth - 1);
    return [0, 0, 0, 0, subArray, subArray, subArray, subArray, subArray, subArray];
  }
}

var array = createArrayWithDepth(3);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: These work great, I'll stare at this code until I understand it more, worked in my app after tweaking some other code.

How you build arrays seems to effect any object properties on each array, array[5][5][5][5].o for example.

Working great now though.

Answer (score 1):

Building an fractal array with an recursion

```js
// pattern
var p = [0, 0, 0, 0, [], [], [], [], [], [] ];

var res = (function fractal(a, depth) {
    return depth == 0 ? a: a.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? fractal(p, depth-1) : e);
})(p, 2);


document.write(JSON.stringify(res, 0, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good method.

I am just a little confused with the ?, the 'e' in the arrow function, and how that whole line works?

Thanks man!

Comment: @Chris it's [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator, it checks if the condition is true `Array.isArray(e)` return first part `fractal(p, depth-1)` else return second part `e`. `e` is current element in the array

Comment: Is there a way of doing something similar to loop through the array returning for example 

(5 for loops, i, j, o, u, k), and changing all 5th level (k) elements, 

array[i][j][o][u][k][0] = 0;
array[i][j][o][u][k][1] = 0;

Comment: @Chris I do not quite understand the question, if you want to iterate the array with five level - yes, you can use five `for` loops or recursion as well